# Convert STRING to TIME bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column with **strings**, which actually represent times.

started_time
7:00
8:45
6:12
15:10
...

I would like to convert column to TIME column, so i tried with this queries:

```
 (1) select *,
    
        CAST(started_time AS TIME) AS startTIME 
        from xx.yy


  (2)  SELECT *,
    PARSE_TIME("%H%M", started_time) as parsed_time
    FROM xx.yy
```

In both cases I got an error **Invalid time string "9:00"**

Is there a way to solve this issue? Is it possible that an error is showing up because there is number 0 missing at the beginning of string (for example 9:00 instead of 09:00)?

Comment: The function for this is called `PARSE_TIME`, please check its documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time_functions#parse_time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the colon in the `parse_time()` function:

```
select t.*, parse_time('%H:%M', started_time)
from (select '7:00' as started_time union all
      select '9:00' union all
      select '8:45' union all
      select '6:12' union all
      select '15:10'
     ) t
```